# Pandas - Split every element of column in dataframe and add to list

Tags: python, pandas, split

So I have a dataframe that has a column like the following:

```
Fruit
apple;banana
pear;apple;peach
blueberry;durian;apple;peach
banana;grape;orange
.
```

and so on. I want to create an end list where I can get the following list:

```
fruitList = ['apple','banana','pear','apple','peach','blueberry','durian','peach','banana','grape','orange']
```

How would I do this? I managed to do this for a single row like the following:

```
 fruitList.extend(df['Fruit'].iloc[0].split(';'))
 #fruitList = ['apple','banana']
```

But of course, that only works for one row... how do I generalize this? My plan is just to count the fruit and get the top 10 fruit counts. My end goal is just to keep those rows that include a top 10 fruit... but to get there, how would I come up with `fruitList` in the first place?

Comment: iloc[0] refers to the first row. using a for loop you can generalize this. can you add more data?

Comment: @sera I guess I could do this with a loop over ever single dataframe row, but with a very large dataframe wouldn't this be slow? I was just wondering if there was an inbuilt way to do this in `pandas` if that makes sense. And yes, I can add more data examples

Comment: @sera In Python we avoid doing loop as much as possible. Alway search for a vectorized way of doing things. Dive into Stackoverflow looking for problems like yours or post a question about.

Comment: I see I was lazy and didn't read the entire question. Good work @sera.

Comment: @srodriguex my answer was an addition. good work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to srodriguex answer:

```
from collections import Counter

all = df.Fruit.str.split(';').sum()
c = Counter(all)
c.most_common(3)
```

Now if you want to get the rows:

```
df[df['Fruit'].str.contains("peach")]
```

and to get the indices:

```
list(df[df['Fruit'].str.contains("apple")].index)
```

Results

```
[('apple', 3), ('peach', 2), ('pear', 1)]


                         Fruit
1              pear;apple;peach
2  blueberry;durian;apple;peach


[1, 2]
```

Comment: @ocean800 I just modified my answer. see how you can get the rows

Comment: @ocean800 glad that i helped. see also my last modification. you can get the indices of the rows

Answer (score 2):

```
df.Fruit.str.split(';').sum()
```

See full code in [Microsft Azure Notebook](https://notebooks.azure.com/n/FLaUtiA0SZQ/notebooks/Question%2047243861.ipynb).

Comment: Didn't realize I could use `sum()` on lists like this thanks :)